# Bind to zooming and dragging at jVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

Does jVectorMap has built-it methods to bind map zooming and map mouse dragging? I did not found them at documentation.

I want to do something like this.

```
var map = $('#world-map').vectorMap();

map.on('zoom', function(){
    ..
})
```

Sure i can bind to element where jvectormap was initialized, like

```
$('#world-map').on('mousewheel', functon(){
    ..
})
```

But it will looks like 'fast-solution'..

Comment: Your "fast-solution" is probably what jvectormap would do internally anyway.

Comment: yep.. but it is so easy with zooming, determine dragging should be little harder, I thought maybe it is already there and optimized =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use the version 1.1.1, you need add the onViewportChange event in the api events, and in applyTransform method.

Please check http://pastebin.com/s5GwcEMy

Comment: btw new version 1.2.2 has onViewportChange event too

Answer (score 3):

okay, i solved that without built-in solution

For zooming

```
$('#world-map svg').on('mousewheel', functon(){
    console.log('cool, you are zooming')
})
```

For dragging

```
var isPressed = false;
$('#world-map svg').mousedown(function(){
    isPressed = true;
}).mouseup(function(){
    isPressed = false;
}).mousemove(function(){
    if(isPressed){
        console.log('fine, you are dragging')
    }
})
```